# How to put two column images to the right or left column?

Tags: floats, two-column

The paper is two-column format. The two column images latex code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
   \centering
     \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Paper_Fig1}
     \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Paper_Fig2}
     \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Paper_Fig3}
     \caption{1000 voxels ) }
   \end{figure*}
```

My question is how to change it to one column images? I mean put the images 
either to the left or to the right column? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `*` from `figure*`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you are right. thank you so much